# Measuring Microservices - Fault Tolerant

Tags: microservices

One of the Microservices Architecture benefit is Fault Tolerant. Which means any issues in one service should not impact other services. As result, it should improve the particular service availability. However, some implementation such as HA, auto scaling also help in availability. Instead of measuring the general of service availability, how we able to have more specific quantitative measurement that Microservice is benefits in fault tolerant?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking if it's possible to measure the general availability of services? The answer to that is yes. Or are you asking how to measure the benefit of high availability to the business in terms of costs? It's very unclear.

Comment: `One of the Microservices Architecture benefit is Fault Tolerant` - not quite, how about `Cascade failures`? Resilience does not come by default with microservices.

Answer (score 2):

Fault tolerance or resilience has to do more with your internal application architecture than with using Microservices or another architectural style. For example - If you compare a well structured monolith with internal error handling and fallback strategies to a bunch of Microservices that are designed with interdependencies but no built in resilience, the Microservices will be way more likely to fail all together.

Here some ideas of how to build a resilient system:

1. Avoid interdependencies. Most important, but not always possible.
2. Use an infrastructure with built in self-healing capabilities, such as Kubernetes.
3. Use an API gateway with built in resilience, such as Zuul.
4. Use specialized libraries for resilient calling with promises and circuit breakers. Such as Hystrix.
5. Cache requests in a stream processor, such as Kafka, to protect against load spikes, intermittent service failures.
6. Design your APIs idempotent.

When you ask for measuring fault tolerance you should look into automated testing of your application. For example you can write tests for your application that use randomized input/wrong input or ultra-high loads in an attempt to disturb the services. So measuring/proving fault tolerance really is a task for the testing team.